# import crowdcount to python shows error even once i installed it

Tags: python

I would like to import this models to my python code

```
import os
import torch
import numpy as np
import sys
from datetime import datetime

from src.crowd_count import CrowdCounter
from src import network
from src.data_loader import ImageDataLoader
from src.timer import Timer
from src import utils
from src.evaluate_model import evaluate_model
```

when I run my code it shows this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-e118d9908bd9> in <module>
      5 from datetime import datetime
      6 
----> 7 from src.crowd_count import CrowdCounter
      8 from src import network
      9 from src.data_loader import ImageDataLoader

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

I installed the crowdcount and also shows this error
the problem with src if I did only
import crowdcount it works fine

Answer (score -1):

Try reinstalling it; checking it's source file OR checking what versions it supports

Comment: the problem with src if I did only import crowdcount it works fine

Comment: @nooonaalnon what do you mean? Please update your post to *show* this with code.